# Can a toilet be covered if the votes are tied in Drunter und Drüber?

Tags: drunter-und-druber

In the game [Drunter und Drüber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drunter_und_Dr%C3%BCber) a tile that covers a toilet must be voted on by all players. The rules say that the tile is placed if the yes votes exceed the no votes, and the tile is not places if the no votes exceed the yes votes.  But what if the votes are equal?

We ruled that in that case the tile is not placed, but the rules are not clear on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**On a tie vote, the Yes votes carry.**

Mayfair Games released this game as [*Wacky Wacky West*](http://mayfairgames.com/game.php?id=87&stock=MFG4104&name=Wacky+Wacky+West), on their website is a [play demonstration/rules explanation video.](http://mayfairgames.com/video.php?id=275)

At about 3:15 the voting is explained and contains this:

> If there are more yes votes than no votes or if it's a tie the tile is played and the outhouse is destroyed.

On BoardGameGeek, there is a file uploaded entitled [Rule clarification - tied voting](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/24602/rule-clarification-tied-voting-doc) which has:

> The German rules state the following:
>
> "Ueberwiegen die Ja-Stimmen oder waren Nein- und Ja-Stimmen gleich stark, bleibt das Plaettchen ueber dem Toilettenhaeuschen liegen."
>
> This can be translated as follows: If there are more "Ja" votes than "Ne" votes, or if the "Ja" and "Ne" votes are equally strong, the tile remains in place.

Answer (score 2):

I found some rules [here](http://www.gamecabinet.com/sumoRulesBank/DrunterUndDruber.html).

Wow, here's some tricky wording.  Emphasis mine for this quote:

> If there are **more yes votes than no votes** then the player lays the tile in the normal way. If however the number of no votes **beats** the yes votes then the player returns the tile to his hand.

It clearly says "Yes > No" to place the tile. However, it doesn't actually say "No > Yes;" rather, it says "No *beats* Yes".

My interpretation of that is that the number of **yes votes must be strictly greater than the no votes** to cover a toilet; otherwise, including on a tie, the nos have it.

Comment: That was my idea too. The Yes = No is not covered in the rules.